# UITextView to detect another developer's app's links

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios13, ios12, uitextviewdelegate

I have a UITextView that I want to be able to recognize another developers app links.

The iPhone notepad app detects the link from that developer and when i tap on it notepad opens the other developer's app correctly. but when the same link is in my UITextView it shows up as non-tappable plain text.

I have my UITextView to detect all data types in the storyboard.

Comment: did you find a solution please?

Comment: not yet. Im still looking for a solution.